# Why does compiling Holden Karau's spark-testing-base generate an error?

Tags: testing, apache-spark, sbt

I am trying to use [Holden Karau's spark-testing-base](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base) using sbt and get 4 errors. It looks like sbt is generating invalid references to 4 jars.

The errors are:

```
[error] 4 not found
[error]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0.test-jar
[error]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-hdfs/2.6.0/hadoop-hdfs-2.6.0.test-jar
[error]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient/2.6.0/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.6.0.test-jar
[error]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-yarn-server-tests/2.6.0/hadoop-yarn-server-tests-2.6.0.test-jar
```

My build.sbt contains:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
 "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.1",
 "org.scalacheck" %% "scalacheck" % "1.12.4",
 "com.holdenkarau" %% "spark-testing-base" % "1.6.1_0.3.3"
 )

parallelExecution in Test := false

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
 settings(
 name := "core",
 version := "1.0",
 scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
)
```

And my test class is from [Holden's wiki example](https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base/wiki/SharedSparkContext):

```
import org.scalatest._
import com.holdenkarou.SharedSparkContext

class SampleTest extends FunSuite with SharedSparkContext {
  test("test initializing spark context") {
    val list = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(list)

    assert(rdd.count === list.length)
  }
}
```

When I execute `sbt test` I get a bunch of maven updates followed by the errors listed above.

It appears that sbt is generating invalid jar names - for example `https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-common/2.6.0/hadoop-common-2.6.0.test-jar` should be `hadoop-common-2.6.0-test.jar` (i.e. the separator after the `2.6.0` should be `-`, not `.`).

Can someone guide me as to why this is occurring, and how to fix it?

Comment: What sbt version are you using?

Comment: Anything on this? I am getting same errors, my sbt version is 0.13.8